# masking and layering images in php

Tags: php, image-processing, gd

I would like to create a script where a user can upload an image and see what it would look like on a sweatshirt. For example:

[image: yummy sweater]

I would start with a blank sweatshirt images such as this:

[image: blank]

Ad then want to over lay the uploaded image, preserving the details and shadows of the sweatshirt.

This possible in PHP? What is the best way to go about it?

Comment: It should be possible with GD library in php

Answer (score 0):

1. you need - the white image png - transparent image in which the inner part will be transparent  and outer part will be white bg.
2. use following plugin for overlay and save.

http://www.addyosmani.com/resources/canvasphoto/

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it.

Make the second image you provided semi transparent on the green region seen below.

[image: Sweatshirt]

The rest of the image should have no opacity (white background). What you can do from here is draw the image to be previewed on the sweatshirt. Then you can draw the image I mentioned above over it. This will provide a mask type effect and you can tweak it from there.

While this will get the job done, I highly suggest you look into HTML5 Canvas for the preview as it has a lot more versatility in comparision to PHP's GD library and it doesn't require any server resources. You can edit the preview in real time and even save the canvas as an image.